# Definite integral: exponential times non-integer powers

Tags: definite-integrals

I would like to calculate:
$$
\int_0^1 \sqrt{1+ a x^2} e^{-a x^2/c} \, \mathrm{d}x
$$
for any positive constants $a,c>0$. I am happy with any closed expression involving any kind of special functions.

Failed attempts so far:

- standard changes of variables seem not to effectively simplify this integral. Indeed one can change variables (e.g. $ax^2/c\to y$) to simplify the dependence on parameters, but I am not able to reduce the indefinite integration to a known one.
- Mathematica fails
- I am not able to find this integral (or a similar one, or those integrals that I get by change of variables) on the standard references, e.g. Gradshteyn–Ryzhik.
- Contour integration: this I did not try extensively by lack of a reasonable contour. Anyway, the integrand has singularities $\pm \tfrac{i}{\sqrt{a}}$ (choose the standard branch cut of $\sqrt{.}$ on the negative real semi-axis) and $\infty$.
- Exploiting the symmetries of the integrand also does not seem to be of use.

Comment: The integral is "worse" than that of the Gaussian and does not seem to be a common expression, so don't hope too much for a ready-made function.

Comment: Did you try integration by parts?

Comment: The obnoxious thing about integration is how easy it is to create "simple-looking" integrals that have no closed form. This seems likely to be one of them.

Comment: @terrace let me confess straight away that Mathematica was my first attempt. I seem to recall that IbP is a standard routine in Mathematica integration, so I did not try it myself. I tried standard ODE methods in the parameters though (e.g. differentiate w.r.t. a, see if the quantity solves and ODE in a and try to solve that), but this was also no use

Comment: @YvesDaoust indeed this does not look too nice. I was hoping to have some expression in terms of hypergeometric functions. For instance the same integral from $0$ to $\infty$ evaluates to a precise hypergeometric function of the parameters...

Comment: Even for $a=c=1$, the value of the definite integral $$\displaystyle\int_0^1 \sqrt{1+x^2}e^{-x^2} \, \mathrm{d}x \,\, \approx 0.8319314795 \dots$$ does not show up on the [Inverse Symbolic Calculator](http://wayback.cecm.sfu.ca/projects/ISC/ISCmain.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\int_0^1\sqrt{1+ax^2}~e^{-\frac{ax^2}{c}}~dx$

$=\int_0^1\sqrt{1+ax}~e^{-\frac{ax}{c}}~d(\sqrt{x})$

$=\dfrac{1}{2}\int_0^1x^{-\frac{1}{2}}(1+ax)^\frac{1}{2}e^{-\frac{ax}{c}}~dx$

$=\Phi_{1}\left(\dfrac{1}{2},-\dfrac{1}{2},\dfrac{3}{2};-a,-\dfrac{a}{c}\right)$ (according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Humbert_series)

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you very much! I am also impressed by the simplification of all constants in front of the integral...